# Simple video player in QT playing audio only

Tags: qmainwindow, qmediaplayer

I written a program that is supposed to show video as well as audio using QT. However I cannot work out why the video is not playing, while the audio works fine.

vidpb.pro

```
QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = vidpb
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY = multimedia
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class QMediaPlayer;
class QVideoWidget;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QMediaPlayer *player;
    QVideoWidget *widget;

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QtMultimedia>
#include <qvideowidget.h>
#include "qmediaplayer.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/sdcard/Movies/video1.mp4"));

    widget = new QVideoWidget(this);
    player->setVideoOutput(widget);
    widget->show();

    setCentralWidget(widget);
    this->show();
    player->play();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Can the file be played? Do you need to register a codec with QT? Have you tried using a simple player using the sample here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qmediaplayer.html ?

Comment: @PreetSangha the file just played audio, but video didnt show. i think problem in videowidget, but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: So did you test it with other samples. Did you try and debug it with logging etc?

Comment: @PreetSangha i tested on mobile phone, on Tiny210 board, but just had sound, no display video

Comment: The issue is you need to isolate the problem. The kinds of things I would do is a. turn on all logging. b. test with multiple files of different codecs c. test with multiple qt examples (like I said) d. test the whole lot again on a different machine. Only then can you compare them to narrow down where the error might be. at this moment there are too many variables to narrow down your problem.

Comment: do you have to use QVideoWidget::setGeometry if it is embedded in a window?